# Troubles setting up BottomNavigationView + Navigation Componenent

Tags: android, android-fragments, exception, bottomnavigationview, kotlin-android-extensions

I'm converting my app to use  one activity and added the BottomnavigationView, and in an effort to prevent fragments being recreated, making unecessary api calls, when navigating between fragments. However I can't make it work:

- No fragment is shown
- Icons are not swithed
- Touching bottom menu items doesn't switch fragments
- Touching the selected item crashes the app with a TypeCastException:  `kotlin.TypeCastException: null cannot be cast to non-null type androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment at com.example.testapp.NavigationExtensionsKt$setupItemReselected$1.onNavigationItemReselected`

Activity's layout:

```
<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/nav_view"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />
```

BottomNav menu:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_1"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_1"
        android:title="@string/title_1" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/homeFragment"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_2"
        android:title="@string/home" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_3"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_3"
        android:title="@string/title_3" />
</menu>
```

In the MainActivity:

```
    class MainActivity : DaggerAppCompatActivity() {

    private var currentNavController: LiveData<NavController>? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        nav_view.itemIconTintList = null

        if(savedInstanceState == null){
            setupBottomNavigationBar()
        } // Else, need to wait for onRestoreInstanceState

    }

    override fun onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState: Bundle) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState)
        // Now that BottomNavigationBar has restored its instance state
        // and its selectedItemId, we can proceed with setting up the
        // BottomNavigationBar with Navigation
        setupBottomNavigationBar()
    }

    private fun setupBottomNavigationBar() {
        val bottomNavigationView = findViewById<BottomNavigationView>(R.id.nav_view)

        val navGraphIds = listOf(R.navigation.mobile_navigation, R.navigation.settings)
        val menuItemsIds = listOf(R.id.navigation_1, R.id.homeFragment, R.id.navigation_3)
        val defaultIconsIds = listOf(R.drawable.ic_1,  R.drawable.ic_2, R.drawable.ic_3)
        val selectedIconsIds = listOf(R.drawable.ic_1a, R.drawable.ic_2a, R.drawable.ic_3a)

        // Setup the bottom navigation view with a list of navigation graphs (custom extension)
        val controller = bottomNavigationView.setupWithNavController(
            navGraphIds = navGraphIds,
            menuItemsIds = menuItemsIds,
            defaultIconsIds = defaultIconsIds,
            selectedIconsIds = selectedIconsIds,
            fragmentManager = supportFragmentManager,
            containerId = R.id.nav_host_container,
            intent = intent
        )

        currentNavController = controller

        // updating icons
        nav_view.menu.iterator().forEach {
            if (it.isChecked) {
                it.setIcon(selectedIconsIds[menuItemsIds.indexOf(it.itemId)])
            } else {
                it.setIcon(defaultIconsIds[menuItemsIds.indexOf(it.itemId)])
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        return currentNavController?.value?.navigateUp() ?: false
    }
}
```

NavigationExtensions:

```
   //.....
    //....

    private fun BottomNavigationView.setupItemReselected(
    menuItemsIds: List<Int>,
    defaultIconsIds: List<Int>,
    selectedIconsIds: List<Int>,
    graphIdToTagMap: SparseArray<String>,
    fragmentManager: FragmentManager) {
    setOnNavigationItemReselectedListener { item ->

        this.menu.iterator().forEach { it ->
            it.setIcon(defaultIconsIds[menuItemsIds.indexOf(it.itemId)])
        }

        item.setIcon(selectedIconsIds[menuItemsIds.indexOf(item.itemId)])

        val newlySelectedItemTag = graphIdToTagMap[item.itemId]
        val selectedFragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(newlySelectedItemTag) as NavHostFragment //TypeCastException happens here
        val navController = selectedFragment.navController
        // Pop the back stack to the start destination of the current navController graph
        navController.popBackStack(
            navController.graph.startDestination, false
        )
    }
}
```

The screen is blank without any fragment view rendered.

Anyone can help me fix this? Am I missing something?

PS: The code is taken from an open source app that can be found [here](https://github.com/immuni-app/immuni-app-android/blob/development/app/src/main/java/it/ministerodellasalute/immuni/ui/main/MainActivity.kt)

[Edit] Adding NavGraph:

1. mobile_navigation

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/homeFragment"
    android:name="com.example.testapp.homeFragment"
    android:label="@string/home"
    tools:layout="@layout/home_fragment" >

    <action
        android:id="@+id/homrFragment_to_detailsFragment"
        app:launchSingleTop="true"
        app:enterAnim="@anim/fragment_open_enter"
        app:exitAnim="@anim/fragment_open_exit"
        app:destination="@id/detailsFragment" />
</fragment>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/navigation_1"
    android:name="com.example.testapp.Fragment_S"
    android:label="@string/fragment_s"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_s" >
    <action
       android:id="@+id/action_navigation_1_to_detailsFragment"
        app:destination="@id/detailsFragment"
        app:enterAnim="@anim/slide_in_right"
        app:exitAnim="@anim/slide_in_left" />
</fragment>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/navigation_3"
    android:name="com.example.testapp.Fragment3"
    android:label="@string/fragment_ss"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_ss" />


<dialog
    android:id="@+id/detailsFragment"
    android:name="com.example.testapp.DetailsFragment"
    android:label="InDetails"
    tools:layout="@layout/layout_details">

    <argument
        android:name="arg1"
        android:defaultValue=""
        app:argType="string"/>

    <argument
        android:name="arg2"
        android:defaultValue=""
        app:argType="string" />
</dialog>
```

2. Navigation Settings:

   ```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Setting up a BottomNavigationView may be a little tricky to setup with Navigation Components, but I think the code you are following as example is a little over engineered and/or serves purposes way more complex than those of an initial code.

I'd have asked in a comment (don't have enough rep), but can you post the NavGraph as well? Setting up the Navigation Controller is extremely easy once you have the NavGraph, the menu and the layout properly set, but all these must be meticulously synced and the documentation in this area is not really that good.

Until you reply with the navgraph, I'll try to help with the solution:

First, change your

```
<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
```

to

```
<fragment
```

but add the following tags

```
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/your_nav_graph.xml"
```

then, make sure the id's on your menu.xml match the same id for the destination you want, as described in your Nav Graph, for example, you should have 3 destinations called

```
android:id="@+id/navigation_1"

android:id="@+id/homeFragment"

android:id="@+id/navigation_3"
```

You won't need to setup any actions.

After that, just execute this in the activity with the BottomNavigationView:

```
NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(your_bottom_navigation_view, findNavController(R.id.your_navigation_fragment))
```

Navigation should work properly after this, without the need to setup everything  on that "setupBottomNavigationView()" method, or the navigation extensions you also posted.

This way, navigation handles everything, from backtstack, to highlighting the proper button on the BottomNavigationView.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The method you provide is what I had before trying to switch to the implementation I'm facing problem with. However, the fragments are recreating triggering api calls each time user switch to the fragment. So I was trying to find a way the fragments wont recreate and the app from the linked source work similarly to what I want to achieve

Comment: Well, I guess you're not allowed to post comments yet... I'll update with the navgraph shortly. But it's a simple graph with no complexity

Comment: Apparently, I'm allowed on my answers for the moment.
I see the problem. I don't think Navigation Components would be the best way to go if its being setup like that. Completely defeats the purpose.
I'd recommend maybe using a viewpager or managing fragment transactions yourself,

Comment: Well, I'm trying to avoid boilerplate code as much as possible. Going the way you are suggesting wouldn't really help in my case. The example I linked is what I think may help, because their app behaves exactly the way I'd like mine to behave

Comment: Updated my question with both navgraphs

Comment: Well, I managed to make it work by adding navgraph for each toplevel destination (fragments)